# How to sort List<List<UInt32>> according to List<UInt32>[0] number ASC/DESC in C#?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, uint32

How shall sort this in ASC order?

I got `List<List<UInt32>>` full of records of `List<UInt32>` and I want those records to be sorted according to the first column in each record - the column is UInt32 number.

So:

I have List of:

```
new List<UInt32>: 32,1,1,1,1,1
new List<UInt32>: 22,2,2,2,2,2
new List<UInt32>: 32,1,1,1,1,1
new List<UInt32>: 1,1,1,1,1
```

which should be sorted to:

```
List<UInt32>: 1,1,1,1,1
List<UInt32>: 22,2,2,2,2,2
new List<UInt32>: 32,1,1,1,1,1
new List<UInt32>: 32,1,1,1,1,1
```

-> Only first number matter! others are not important for sorting. I'm lookin for ASC thing, but both would be fantastic so when I think algorithm should be changed, I'll look it up :)

Thank you for your effort to help !

@Samuel, Thank you, I'll try to implement it when I try to change the type :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nearly a duplicate of:

[How to sort List<List<string>> according to List<string> number of fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721577/how-to-sort-listliststring-according-to-liststring-number-of-fields)

Something like:

```
var sorted = parent.OrderBy( l => l[0] );
```

Or:

```
parent.Sort( (a,b) => a[0].CompareTo( b[0] ) )
```

Comment: yes, nearly, but I'm learning the stuff and need it also now, so I'm really sorry I'm making ALMOST duplicates, but I don't think it's a bad idea.. Thank you

Comment: This error pops at "parent.sort" -> Error 1 Identifier expected

Comment: the first example's doing the same. Identifier expected. at [0]

Comment: The dot after 'l' is wrong - should read just 'l[0]' instead of 'l.[0]'.

Comment: Oops, fixed.  I feel dumb now.

I guess that's what I get for not testing code.

Comment: it's ok I found it straightaway :)

Comment: Hi, any reason this wouldn't work?: temp.Sort((a, b) => a[1].CompareTo(b[1])); it says that it's out of index but it is not, I check it with IF statement befoer..

Answer (score 3):

While John's answer works, I would suggest using `First()` instead of accessing the 0 element in the list. This way it works for any `IEnumerable<T>` not just `IList<T>`.

```
var sorted = list.OrderBy(subList => subList.First());
```

Comment: If you wish, but both answers are short enough to be seen if they look.

Comment: May be it should even be FirstOrDefault() to avoid a exception in case of an empty sub item.

Comment: You could, but with .First() and an empty sub list, the sequence returned will be empty.